# How to export a jar that can include the whole project using android studio?

Tags: android, jar

This application is a customized View which has a 3d effect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7i7f.png)

Please notice the contents which are surrounded by the red box.
*.so is a C++ SDK which contains some 3d animation effects.

I want to make this whole project into a widget SDK, so I can simply reuse it in my other project.

Could anybody give me some suggestions how to make it happened?

Here is my build.gradle, unfortunately this gradle export a jar I can not use, which I think the reason that it is lacked of *.so.

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        main{
            jniLibs.srcDirs=['libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}

//task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldJar(type:Delete){
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

//task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type:Copy){
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    //give whatever name you want to give
    rename('classes.jar','icreatorSDK.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar,build)
```

Waiting for your advice. Thank you!